# "Cannot prove that Object <:< Try[U]" in flattened function

Tags: scala, implicit-typing

I have a `Map` that has the possibility of having a nested map of the same type. Each of those nested maps have a reference back to the outer map.

I've defined a `findValue` method that looks through the current map, if it doesn't find anything, it goes to its parent, and so on until reaching `null` which is the parent of the outermost `SymbolTable`.

I've put this behaviour into a `Try`, so that I can match on `Success` and `Failure`; however in order to avoid having a type a-la `Try[Try[Try[ ... Try[TableVaue]... ]]]` I flatten the output.

In trying to call `flatten` I get the following error: `Cannot prove that Object <:< Try[U]`

Here are the relevant bits of code:

```
class SymbolTable(val parentScope: SymbolTable) {
  type TableValue = (TypeInfo, Option[Expression], Option[SymbolTable])

  private val contents: mutable.Map[String, TableValue] = mutable.Map.empty

  private def findValue(key: String): Try[TableValue] = Try {
    if (contents contains key) contents(key)
    else parentScope findValue key
  }.flatten
}
```

So my question is: How do I make this work without any major refactoring of my code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if (contents contains key) contents(key)
else parentScope findValue key
```

The type of this expression is the LUB of `TableValue` (the result of `contents.apply`) and `Try[TableValue]` (the result of `findValue`), and that is `AnyRef` (or `java.lang.Object`).

The following would probably work:

```
if (contents contains key) Try(contents(key))
else parentScope findValue key
```

but the whole expression is not good. `Try` is only useful if you cannot avoid having to catch exceptions which is not the case here. You can perfectly use `Map#get` to retrieve an `Option`. With `Option` it becomes much simpler:

```
def findValue(key: String): Option[TableValue] =
  contents.get(key).orElse(parentScope.findValue(key))
```

If `parentScope` can be `null` you must guard against that too, returning `None` directly.

Comment: You're probably right about using option instead of try. success and failure are just more readable in terms of intent as error/no-error than option is

Comment: @ElectricCoffee I don't write Scala very often (not as often as I would like), but I would not expect walking up a tree to result in `Success | Failure[A]` I would expect `Some[A] | None` since it is a search. I often write C# and I call `xs.FirstOrDefault()` and never `xs.First()` unless I either know `xs` isn't empty or I want execution to fail if it is empty. I do _not_ want `InvalidOperationException("Sequence contains no elements")` to be caught. Granted, Scala idioms may be different in this case.